# No mostrar modal en la seccion principal si no se realizó un filtro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dentro de mi plataforma tengo una seccion de productos (stock/products) en el cual se muestran todos los productos sin filtrar por categoria ni tipo de stock. Dentro de esa seccion me muestra un modal que dice:

Estas filtrando por: 
categoria:Todos los productos / todos los productos.

Este mismo esta bien que figure pero solamente cuando estoy claramente utilizando alguno de los filtros, ya sea por stock por categoria u otro. pero no deberia figurar en esta pagina central donde se muestra todo sin filtrar.

Esta es mi funcion:

```
var categoryId = getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href);

var applyFilterCategory = function () {
    $('#categoriesFilter').val(categoryId);
    $('#categoriesFilter').trigger("liszt:updated");

    $('.categoryFilterApplied').text($('#categoriesFilter option:selected').text());
    $('.categoryFilterText').show();
    $('.productVisibility').text(setVisibilityFilterText('allProducts'))
    $('.appliedFilters').show();
};
```

De que manera limitar que cuando categorias sea igual a 'todos los productos' no se muestre ese modal? O que al estar en la url 'stock/products' no se muestre?

Aqui dejo la funcion apenas carga la pagina se aplica, y es donde llamo a applyFilterCategory:

```
var loadCategoriesFilter = function() {
    var url = '/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/';

    $.post(url, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            categories = [];
            $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
            categories.push(element);
            });
            getParentCategories(categories);            
        }
    }, 'json').done(function() {
        applyFilterCategory();

    });
};
```

y loadCategoriesFilter se carga apenas se ingresa a la pagina de stock/products:

```
$(function() {
    var modifiedProductIds = new Array(); // 

   if (!emptyProducts) {

        loadCategoriesFilter();
        loadStockFilter();

        var categoryId = getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href);
        var params = {};
        var filter = {};      

        if(categoryId !== null) {
            params.page = 1;
            filter.category = categoryId;
        } 

        applyFilter(params, filter);
    }
```

Comment: En donde y como llamas a la funcion `applyFilterCategory()`?

Comment: @alanfcm ahi edite y cargue la funcion donde llamo al applyFilterCategory( )

Comment: Que es lo que devuelve el `response.categoryTree`?